# Compilation of ROS2 on QNX

Tags: ros2, build-from-source, ros-galactic

while building ROS2 Galactic for QNX using steps mentioned on https://ros2-qnx-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/galactic/build_from_source.html, i am getting the following error:

[image]

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Please do not use images of text. Instead, copy/paste the text and format as code.

Comment: What is your question about the first UserWarning? The text seems very clear.